# Nhibernate - lock DB

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I'm using Nhibernate for the first time and I 've noticed that when I call BeginTransaction method it lock my Database.
Instead, entity framework (ObjectContext or DbContext too) keeps all changes in memory and SaveChange method work perfectly if no error occurs without lock anything on db.

Has Nhibernate some feautres like EF?

Comment: You may want to play with `IsolationLevel`. The default is `ReadCommitted`, but you may change it on `BeginTransaction`. I had to use Snapshot on a certain project.

Comment: Have you measured the performance and identified that the transactions are a bottle neck?

Comment: I hate anything about resource locking. But I admit sometime they are useful, however I prefer a behavior similar to entity framework as default. Where can I set IsolationLevel option in Nhibernate?

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325(v=vs.100).aspx: `Only operations against the data source are transacted. Changes made to objects in the object context are not transacted`. I interpret that as that the queries are made in a transaction and hence the `SaveChanges()` are made in the same transaction = same behavior as for nhibernate. How could EF else make sure that nothing is overwritten in the DB?

Comment: Sure. It is. So, how can I get the same behavior in NHIbernate? I want to change many and any object, add, delete, edit, and finally, call "SaveChange" method. All example I've seen instaed, starts with begin tansaction (locking db), then changes some entity and finally call commit. The range time about DB locking is different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using optimistic concurrency, then you could do something like this:

```
MyEntity myEntity;
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    myEntity = session.Get<MyEntity>(id);
    scope.Complete();
}

// No longer in a transaction...
myEntity.Add(something);
myEntity.Update(somethingElse);

// Later, possibly in another request...

using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    session.Update(myEntity);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

As long as a transaction is open (depdending on your isolation level as noted above) you will likely have shared locks on the tables and keys involved in the initial selects, which will block updates to those tables until the transaction completes.  If you want to avoid having those locks, you can suppress the transaction for the read, perform modifications, and then attempt to update the object later.  The version number on the entity should protect you from lost updates.

Note that you don't have to suppress the read transaction.  If you want to block until all writes are committed, you can still require a transaction around the read as long as it is separate from the update transaction and is completed as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't like it..I think it would be better implementing something like entity framework already does, for instance I could mantain all changes in memory with my custom object and finally, calling BeginTransaction-Commit of NHibernate. By this way I'll do exactly what EF does. What do you think about?

Comment: If you are saving a new object, then you can construct the object graph before opening the session and starting the transaction.  If you are updating an object, the only ways to perform "in memory" updates without holding locks are to: 1) read the objects without a transaction (suppress it); 2) read the objects in a transaction and end the transaction before updating the objects; or 3) relax your transaction isolation level (which will still hold some locks).  If detaching the object graph from the session is an issue, it is possible to use multiple transactions in a single session.